# creating script to check LastWriteTime, If over 12hrs "Do something"

Tags: powershell-3.0

I want to create a script that checks to see if a log file has been written to, if that period of time is over 12hrs I would like it to email via smtp. The email part is written and working, I just need to know how to check if more than 12hrs have elapsed since the last write.

```
$source =  'C:\Logs\Test.log'
(Get-Item $source).LastWriteTime

if(Get-Item $source).LastWriteTime
```

Due to my lack of coding skills I am not proficient with if statements. This is where i require help.

Comment: Tutorials exist on the net. SO does not strive to replace them. But to answer your question, the syntax in PowerShell would look like this: `if ((Get-Item $source).LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddHours(-12))`.

Comment: Thank you Ansgar